# finding a subtring in a string and if it does exist insert it into another table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column that holds rows that are a very, very long string that may or may not have a specific substring that I need to insert into another table and the position of that substring varies.

Example: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse porttitor mattis neque id pharetra. Proin egestas magna id pellentesque vulputate. houseid:1234 Vivamus cursus at enim eget tempor. Nunc porttitor eget dolor nec hendrerit. Ut dapibus elit id tortor commodo, eget molestie mi dictum. '

Hence I need a query that first:

- checks if the substring ' houseid:1234' exists and probably I need a regex expression here since the id varies. Can I use regex in a SQL query?
- the substring position in the string is uncertain
- Only if  that substring does exist I need to insert that substring into another table.

I came across Substring and PatINDEx to get the substring and IF and EXISTS to verify if the substring does exist in the string but I don't know how to put them together

I have this rough query:
IF EXISTS (SELECT houseid:1234  FROM columnName WHERE SUBSTRING(ColumnName, PATINDEX('houseid:1234'), 12))

How can I make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Regex does not apply when you can use LIKE '%houseid:1234%'

Comment: *Can I use regex in a SQL query?* Yes, you can. But trivial INSTR() or LOCATE() is more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont 'put them together' insert into your new table with the above query as a select eg;

```
INSERT INTO 
   schema.table
SELECT 
   substring(target_col, 'house_id:1234')
FROM 
   schema.target_table
WHERE 1=1
   AND substring(target_col, LOCATE(target_col, 'house_id:1234'), 7) = 'house_id:1234'
```

7 assumes the string length is constant, locate returns the index of the first character where the string is in `target_col`.

Comment: Your query will return empty rowset always.